# PSFTP rename file extension

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm using a PSFTP script to upload files to a remote server for processing and there are specific steps that I need to take with file in order for the file to be processed correctly by their system. Specifically, I have to upload the file with a ".u01" in the extension, then rename it to a ".r01". after it has been uploaded.

Is there a way to replace just the extension of the uploaded file? The rest of the filename can't be modified because the filename is corresponds with the contents of the file.

And no, I can't just upload it with a ".r" extension. Tried that already :P

The script is simple. It uploads all files from the "to_upload" directory into "ul" on the remote server:

```
 cd ul
 put -r to_upload/
```

Comment: What happens when you use `REN`/`RENAME`?

Comment: How about showing us the script? Obviously change any proprietary info. Are you uploading to a Windows or *Nix server?

Comment: Added the script. I tried using "ren *.u *.r" but throws an error saying wildcards require a directory. And I think it's a Windows server.

Comment: You have to do @Matt Williamson before your comment for me to get it. I just happened to check back on this one. Are you dynamically creating the script file for PSFTP? If not, that's how you can do it. You write a batch script to create the PSFTP file.